# Flutter gradle-wrapper.properties Not Found

Tags: flutter, android-studio, gradle

My Android gardle settings states that my `gradle-wrapper.properties` file is missing. But the file exists and is valid.

The error:
[image]

The file in the proper location:
[image]

gradlew --version

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-02-08 09:58:38 UTC
Revision:     f0d9291c04b90b59445041eaa75b2ee744162586

Kotlin:       1.5.31
Groovy:       3.0.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          1.8.0_341 (Oracle Corporation 25.341-b10)
OS:           Mac OS X 13.0 x86_64
```

flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.1, on macOS 13.0 22A380 darwin-x64, locale en-IL)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.0.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.70.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I remember, that AS had issues when the gradle folder is not in the root. Maybe one of the following things help:

- Update AS
- Update Gradle
- Invalidate cache
- Reimport project
- Try out IntelliJ

Comment: You can see from my screenshots that the gradle folder located at the android root... I also tried to Invalidate the cache and it didn't help. All other suggestions are not good enough.